Jittering/flickering when drawing Konva line
I am using mapbox and react-konva and when I try to draw a new konva line or polygon, in certain map location, the preview line (the line I am creating) is jittering/flickering. It does not happen all the time and seems to be dependant on the location.
export default function PreviewPolyLine() {
  const [pointerPosition, stageViewState, previewObject] = useEditorStore(
    useShallow((state) => [state.pointerPosition, state.stageViewState, state.previewObject])
  );
  const { renderHandles } = useEditingHandles();

  const stageOffset = { x: stageViewState.x, y: stageViewState.y };
  const stageScale = { x: stageViewState.scaleX, y: stageViewState.scaleY };

  const adjustedPointerPosition = {
    x: (pointerPosition.x - stageOffset.x) / stageScale.x,
    y: (pointerPosition.y - stageOffset.y) / stageScale.y,
  };

  const id = uuid4();

  return (
    <Group key={id}>
      {previewObject && (
        <>
          <Line
            key={previewObject.gl!.id}
            id={previewObject.gl!.id}
            points={[
              ...(previewObject.gl as LineLikeObject).coordinates.flatMap((point) => point),
              adjustedPointerPosition.x,
              adjustedPointerPosition.y,
            ]}
            listening={false}
            stroke={'orange'}
            lineCap={'round'}
            lineJoin={'round'}
            fill={'cyan'}
            opacity={0.5}
            closed={
              previewObject.handles.length > 1 &&
              previewObject.gl?.type === GraphicalObjectType.Polygon
            }
            hitStrokeWidth={16}
            dragDistance={0}
            strokeWidth={4}
            dash={[10, 8]}
          />
          {renderHandles(previewObject, false)}
        </>
      )}
      <Circle
        key={`${id}-preview-circle`}
        id={`${id}-preview-circle`}
        x={adjustedPointerPosition.x}
        y={adjustedPointerPosition.y}
        listening={false}
        radius={5}
        stroke={'orange'}
        strokeWidth={2}
        fillAfterStrokeEnabled
        lineCap={'round'}
        fill={'white'}
        dash={[2, 3]}
      />
    </Group>
  );
}

This is the jittering/flickering that I get:
Preview of flickering issue
The issues seems to be appearing in certain locations on the map.
I tweaked different Konva line attribute values:
perfectDrawEnabled={false}
tension={0}
dash={[12, 6]}
but it did not help.

Make a small online demo, please.
